# What is the rationale behind the `std::unique_XXX` naming convention?

Tags: c++, terminology, naming

It seems like there was a mini-trend to name things `std::unique_XXX` at some point. It makes sense that `std::unique_ptr` is a smart pointer that is only meant to be handled by one consumer, and therefore "unique" in this case makes sense.

But at least one other class got the `unique` moniker and I'm not really sure why. Why is `std::unique_lock` called that? As opposed to `std::lock_guard`, which is not any less or more unique, right?

I think I'm missing something.

I can't recall what other classes followed suit but I seem to remember we have more. Maybe it was just `std::unique_lock`; I forget. But if there are other `std::unique_XXX` class names, why are they named that?

Comment: No, the antonym of unique_lock is shared_lock.  Same idea.

Comment: Ah. I feel dumb now. That suddenly clarifies it. Thank you! I should note that part of why I felt (and maybe still feel a little bit) like I am missing something is that I was focused on the difference between `lock_guard` and `unique_lock` and how that reflects in their name. I think of (and it seems to be presented as such) `unique_lock` as a supercharged version of `lock_guard`. But it's not called `extended_lock_guard` or similar. It's called `unique_lock`, which caused my brain to think that `unique_` was more about whenever we make "a better version" of something. :P

Comment: As in `auto_ptr` => `unique_ptr` = upgraded RAII pointer type... so maybe `unique_` was idiomatic for "better."

Answer (score 3):

A lock guard is locked on creation and unlocked on destruction. You can't move it or copy it, so you can't transfer or share access to the locked resource.

A `std::unique_lock` is (among other things) movable (not copyable). So you can transfer access to the underlying resource. Much like you transfer ownership of a `std::unique_ptr`.

While I can't really comment on why the naming scheme was picked as I wasn't there and haven't read the papers / discussion on the topic... the similarities between the two are at least apparent enough for me to say "yeah I get why they did that." :)

Comment: I'm choosing to interpret this answer as "a class `T` in C++ going forward may be named `unique_` if it satisfies the `moveable<T>` concept but not the `copyable<T>` concept. I wonder if that works?

Answer (score 2):

You mention that `std::unique_ptr` makes sense.

`std::unique_lock` is modeled after `boost::unique_lock`.  [Here's the proposal to put it in the standard.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2406.html)

The paper doesn't seem to mention the reasoning behind the name, but I'm going to **speculate** that the `unique_` prefix is intended to denote a type that:

- Can be "empty"
- Default constructs "empty"
- Can be moved.
- Can be released prior to destruction
- Expressly forbids sharing/copying (There is a [`std::shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) that expressly *allows* sharing)